# Amazon EC2 IP not resolving on a new instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, hosting, resolve

I am creating a backup machine to run simultaneously next to my live machine. I have created a mirror copy of the instance and volume but for some unknown reason when I go to the IP address, I get a 'page canot be displayed' message.

Here are the exact steps I took:

**Create snapshot**

**Create new volume from snapshot**

**Create new instance (Ubuntu Server 12.10)**

**Attach new volume to instance (sda1)**

**Start instance**

**Wait for status checks to complete**

**Associate IP address with instance**

Am I missing something? I assume the IP address should resolve instantly?

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing those steps , You can create AMI out of that instance and launch that instance ,It will be the same copy of earlier instance .